# Importing in conda, undefined `__gfortran` symbols

Tags: python, c++, fortran, conda

When trying to import a package, I get:

```
[me@server ~]$ ipython 
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import cvxopt
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-14abf1b564a4> in <module>()
----> 1 import cvxopt

/home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/__init__.py in <module>()
     30 # You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
     31 
---> 32 import cvxopt.base
     33 
     34 def normal(nrows, ncols=1, mean=0.0, std=1.0):

ImportError: /home/me/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/base.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done
```

My environment is set up completely in conda. What should I do? How do I resolve the gfortran thing with conda only?

Comment: How was the package `cvxopt` installed? The path does not look like conda but a custom install.
Can you try to remove the package, enable the conda virtual environment and rebuild the package?

Comment: so actually, I am in conda root environment (or must i activate some other non-root environment?), I install cvxopt by CVXOPT_BUILD_GLPK=1 pip install cvxopt .... and get the above error... I tried all types of methods in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069796/installing-glpk-cvxopt-with-conda and nothing works.......

Comment: `which python` should return the path to the conda python. If that is the case, you can use `python -m pip install ...` that will use this python instead of your system one.

Comment: so even after I do: $$ python -m  pip install cvxopt  . I still have the error ImportError: /home/me/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cvxopt/base.so: undefined symbol: _gfortran_st_write_done . I do not think this is the issue about wrong pip/python . since [me software_1]$ which pip
~/anaconda2/bin/pip
[me software_1]$ which python
~/anaconda2/bin/python

Comment: There is a conda-forge package, can you remove the existing cvxopt and execute `conda install -c conda-forge cvxopt=1.1.8`? (ref: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cvxopt )

Comment: the issue is that I would need to use integer programmng that are introduced in cvxopt. The version that is required is cvxopt with glpk . the default cvxopt does not have glpk

Comment: Do you have gfortran installed via conda? `conda install gcc` should do. Then, a check that `which gfortran` returns `/home/me/anaconda2/bin/gfortran`.