# Cannot import GLPK in Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, glpk

I searched a lot an answer to my problem but wasn't able to find a fix. 
I'm running anaconda. 
I installed glpk with from conda-forge with the command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge glpk
```

The installation worked fine but then in my notebook, I've got an error message when I try to import the module :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'glpk'

I had no problem to install and import other packages.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [installing glpk cvxopt with conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41069796/installing-glpk-cvxopt-with-conda)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually no, I did install glpk with conda as replied in this post.

Answer (score 1):

The files installed by

```
conda install -c conda-forge glpk
```

can be found at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/glpk/files. Looking at the archives only the GLPK C library is installed and no Python binding or package.

One of the packages that can call the GLPK library from Python is Pulp (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pulp).

Comment: I'm having a problem with that. glpsol is installed in my computer but anaconda is not recognising it apparently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm conda/windows user. I never could import it directly, but based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61889288/1556106) I could make work a library that consume it (pypsa)

Basically, download the library (is in sourceforge) and add it to windows system path

Hope this help to somebody googling this issue. Bests

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make it work:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt.
2. Type `conda activate [your environment]`.
3. Type `conda install -c conda-forge glpk` to install glpk.
4. Type `where glpsol`.
5. Copy the path that keeps the file `glpsol.exe`.

Now you have to set the path in your computer's environment by:

1. Click Start and search for "Edit the system environment variables".
2. Click "Environment Variables...".
3. Double-click "Path" in user variables.
4. Paste the path you got from step 4 (Only the path that keeps the
   file `glpsol.exe`).
5. Click OK and restart your Anaconda.

Hope it works, and sorry for any confusion that might have occurred.